# How to increase ObjectBox database size to prevent ObjectBoxError.dbFull?

Tags: swift, database, objectbox

When I insert large amounts of data into the ObjectBox database, I get errors like `ObjectBoxError.dbFull` and logs like this:

> [ERROR] Storage error code -30792

Once the database is "full", this also happens when e.g. removing data.

There is enough space on my drive left; how can this be solved? Can I give ObjectBox more data?

Answer (score 1):

ObjectBox has a maximum size setting for its database and when it is reached, you get errors like above. This maximum size setting is meant to prevent your database from growing to unexpected sizes; e.g. image you did a programming error and inserted data until your drive is full. Thus, you have to think about any data size your app may ever reach (better be generous here).

The default setting is currently at a relatively low value of 500 MB (may depend on the ObjectBox version). Now, let's have a look at the Store initializer:

```
public init(directory: String = "objectbox", maxDbSizeInKByte: UInt64 = 500 * 1024,
            fileMode: UInt32 = 0o755, maxReaders: UInt32 = 0) throws
```

The `maxDbSizeInKByte` parameter is the one we need. For example, to allow the database to grow up to 2 GB, you would initialize the store like this:

`let store = try Store(directoryPath: myDir, maxDbSizeInKByte: 2 * 1024 * 1024)`

If you don't care about the max size, e.g. on a server with exabytes of storage, set this value to something ridiculously big.

PS.: Removing data can also cause this, as ObjectBox does "copy on write". Thus by removing data, you add a new version of your database (snapshot) first. This e.g. enables multi-version concurrency, allowing readers to work on previous snapshots of the data.